# Bash i can't print all elements of an array but only the last one

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I'm not able to assign all values of for in into an array so i'm able to print only the last one

```
   ###previouse code
    for item2 in "${!TUR[@]}"; do
        ARRAY="${item2}"
    done

    for item in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
        printf "$ARRAY \n";
    done
```

How can i assign succesfully all elements to ARRAY variable and print out all elements?

Comment: you’re not indexing into the array your overwriting the array and thus , the array becomes the last overwrite which is the last element in your TUR array ..

Comment: Your edit isn't the proper solution, you're just appending to the first element. There's a duplicate somewhere, one sec.

Comment: Additionally, in your second loop, you want `printf '%s\n' "$item"`, not `ARRAY`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. In fact isn't the best solution i'm occuring in others troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first issue is to add elements to an array, you do something like `array+=("$item_to_add")`

So, you might have something like this:

```
tur=( A B C D )

for item in "${tur[@]}"; do
    arr+=("$item")
done
for e in "${arr[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\n" "$e";
done
```

BTW: It is best to avoid Bash variable names `INCAPS` since Bash uses these for internal use. The convention is to use lower case for user variable names.

BTW: The second loop is functionally the same as:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

And both loops can be replaced with:

```
arr=("${tur[@]}")             # copy the array
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"     # print the new array
```

Comment: If you expand the variable in the `printf` formatting string, its content will be interpreted as formatting directives, with potentially surprising results – I'd use `printf '%s \n' "$e"` instead (or `'%s\n'` if the space wasn't actually desired).

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Good point. Done. One could also just do `echo "$e"` in this case.

Comment: The latter loop could, of course, be replaced outright with `printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"`, letting `printf` repeat the format string as many times as needed to consume all arguments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Ha! I was just testing that as you were typing! And the first loop can be replaced with `arr=("${tur[@]}")`

Comment: The first loop in the question used `${!TUR[@]}` indirection, though.